# Google Places Auto Complete - Restrict to Major Cities

Tags: google-places-api

I am trying to find out if I can restrict Google Places auto complete to include only Large/Major US Cities and not smaller cities/towns.

For example, we would not allow the user to enter "Montogomery, TX" but instead the user can choose the closest large city "Houston, TX".

"Montgomery, TX" should not appear in the auto complete list but "Houston, TX" should.

Thanks,
Shardul

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that Google Places API does not support the feature I am looking for. We had to work out an alternative based on the Google API.